# Selenium - in same testcase open 2 different pages

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox

Could someone assist me in the following?

I have to create testcase which starts with one page i.e http://page1.
After clicking on send message (on page1), I have to move to page2 and confirm that message has been sent successfully.
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://page1")
driver.find_element_by_id("connectBtn").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_id("short_id")
driver.find_element_by_id("from").send_keys("41587000200")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/form/button").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/h2").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/textarea")
# Check if message exists on SMS Response
driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/h2").click()
driver.close()
```

Before "Check if message on SMS .." I have to go to http://page2 and confirm that exists in a big textbox somethnig like: SMS Delivered Sucessfully.

Could someone provide me with solution?
Thank you in advance

Comment: http://page2 opens in new tab after click?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle new browser window that was opened during your webdriver session than you can try to use following code:

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
# driver.window_handles returns list of available windows to handle. [1] is the second opened window
```

After managing elements on Confirmation window you can go back to main window

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, for a answer. Quite simple but I could not done it without your help

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please accept it by putting the check under Upvote/Downvote total score. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hi  Andersson is very right but   there is another way to resolve your problem simply you can define the path of second page before  that just compare your message with x value